# OpenGL ES 2.0 - the Fragment Shader making everything look blue when applying a Vignette effect

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec, android-gpuimageview

I've been trying to apply the filters I use in the `android-gpuimage` library in the `Mediacodec` surface context. So far I've succeeded in using the filters that only require one extra texture map. However, when I try to apply a filter that needs at least two, the result is an either blue-colored or rainbow-colored mess.

The following issue deals with the one that uses a texture lookup filter and an vignette filter.

The vertex shader I used is as follows:

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 textureTransform;

attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vTexCoordinate;

varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;

void main() {
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
    v_TexCoordinate = (textureTransform * vTexCoordinate).xy;
}
```

The fragment shader I used is as follows:

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require

precision lowp float;

varying highp vec2 v_TexCoordinate;

uniform samplerExternalOES u_Texture; //MediaCodec decoder provided data
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2; //Amaro filter map
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture3; //Common vignette map

void main()
{
    vec3 texel = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate).rgb;

    vec2 red = vec2(texel.r, 0.16666);
    vec2 green = vec2(texel.g, 0.5);
    vec2 blue = vec2(texel.b, 0.83333);

    texel.rgb = vec3(
                     texture2D(inputImageTexture2, red).r,
                     texture2D(inputImageTexture2, green).g,
                     texture2D(inputImageTexture2, blue).b);

    //After further research I found the problem is somewhere below
    vec2 tc = (2.0 * v_TexCoordinate) - 1.0;
    float d = dot(tc, tc);
    vec2 lookup = vec2(d, texel.r);
    texel.r = texture2D(inputImageTexture3, lookup).r;
    lookup.y = texel.g;
    texel.g = texture2D(inputImageTexture3, lookup).g;
    lookup.y = texel.b;
    texel.b = texture2D(inputImageTexture3, lookup).b;
    //The problem is somewhere above

    gl_FragColor = vec4(texel, 1.0);
}
```

The end result of that program looked like this:
[image: The result video - paused]

Is this the result of a bad vignette map, or is it something to do with the vignette application part of the fragment shader?

EDIT:

The texture used for inputImageTexture2:

[image: lomo_map]

The texture used for inputImageTexture3:

[image]

Comment: Can you post image that is used for texture `u_Texture`,  `inputImageTexture2` and `inputImageTexture3`?

Comment: The color can't come from anywhere but inputImageTexture3. Are you sure you're passing the right texture?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The original source had `addInputTexture(R.drawable.vignette_map)`, the `R.drawable.vignette_map` referring to the lower image.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the way I load my textures matters.

My current code for loading textures:

```
public int loadColormap(final Bitmap colormap) {
    IntBuffer textureIntBuf = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureIntBuf);
    int textureHandle = textureIntBuf.get();
    //if (textures[2] != 0) {
    if (textureHandle != 0) {
        //GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[2]);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle);

        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, colormap, 0);
    }

    //if (textures[2] == 0) {
    if (textureHandle == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
    }

    //return textures[2];
    return textureHandle;
}
```

The previous incarnation used the `textures` array, an array I use to load the data from MediaCodec and the watermark. For some reason if I use that instead of generating an `IntBuffer` for each texture, the textures used in the fragment shader get jumbled or something.